# Android accessing BR ids from XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm trying to access BR ids in xml layout file, i've tried to include BR into layout like this (autocomplete when i put dot behind BR shows right values)

```
<layout>
<data>
   <import type="com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR"/>
</data>
   ...
   <Button app:custom_int_attribute="@{BR.some_id}"/>
   ...
</layout>
```

When i try to make project  i get this error, which suggests to me that BR class is created after layouts are compiled(which doesn't make much sense to me):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot resolve type for BR   file:F:\pdt-client-android\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml  loc:36:50 - 36:51   ****\ data binding error ****

I am aware that i can create int variable in layout and assign id to it from activity, but i'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly right.  `BR` fields are code-generated, strongly-typed versions of the values in the resources.  To access resources within resource files, you don't refer to the Java class.  In your example, you would do:

```
    <Button app:custom_int_attribute="@some_id"/>
```

With that said, it's unusual for an id to have no prefix as in your example.  If you were referring to a view in a layout, it would probably be `BR.id.some_id` in Java and `"@+id/some_id"` in xml.  From your use case of assigning to an integer attribute, I'm assuming that you have defined the id in `id.xml` file in the values folder as type `id` or in integers.xml as type `integer`.  In that case, you would access it like this: `"@id/some_id"`, or `"@integer/some_id"` much like you would `"@string/XXX"` or `"@color/XXX"`.

Comment: I already know how to answer regular xml resources in layouts, but sadly that doesn't work for databinding resources.

Comment: why are you trying to access the resource id via binding instead of directly?  It does seem like a chicken/egg problem (BR file is generated from resources, which depend on BR file).  Try exposing a property from your own class and bind to that.  That property can return BR.some_id.  I don't see why you would do that instead of accessing it directly from resource unless you had some logic to choose among different resources, in which case, it makes sense you'd need that logic in your own class anyway.